# php value from random function to stay same after page refresh

Tags: php, random

is there a way that when I use the random function to get a list of random strings to display, it will stay even after i refreshed the page?

Such as this code:

```
session_start();
$a = array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown");


if ( ! isset($_SESSION['rand_val']) ) {
     $_SESSION['rand_val'] = array_rand(array_flip($a)); 
}
try{
        $db = $conn->prepare("Select Column from Table where `xColumn` = XX");
        $db->execute();

        while($row=$db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 
       //if returned 5 values from DB, then randomly generate 5 values.

            echo $row->Column, "<br>";

            echo ($_SESSION['rand_val']), "<br>";
        }


} catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: ".$e;
    }
```

It only get the first value from the array and store into the session.

Comment: You will need to persist this data in one way or another. You can either store that random array on the server using sessions or on the client using cookies. At each page load you check the session/cookie if it exists—if it does, fetch the array. Otherwise generate a new random array and write to it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution:

```
session_start();

$a = array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown");

if ( ! isset($_SESSION['rand_val']) ) {
    $_SESSION['rand_val'] = array_rand(array_flip($a));
}

   
echo $_SESSION['rand_val']; // green (or other values in array)
```

#### If you want multiple items:

```
session_start();

$a = array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown");

if ( ! isset($_SESSION['rand_val']) ) {
    $_SESSION['rand_val'] = array_rand(array_flip($a), 2); // Specify how many random value you want from array
}

   
print_r($_SESSION['rand_val']); // Array ( [0] => blue [1] => yellow )
```

Comment: this will not stop mt_rand from returning a different number each time the page is refreshed.

Comment: Sorry! I misread the question. I changed my answer. I thought he want rand value from the array and that he can't figure out

Comment: @hanshenrik Please check the answer now :)

Comment: Great, Thank you for taking the time to recheck my answer

Comment: Hi thanks! but it doesn't really work? It returns the first item from the array and in number(index), not strings, and I don't understand why

Comment: How many random items do want at a time? One or Many? Currently it's returning index if you want value then you could do this `echo $a[$_SESSION['random_keys']];`

Comment: Updated new anwser please check.

Comment: Because the values would be displayed in a while loop depending on the rows I'm getting from database, so if its 5 rows, I'll be getting 5 random values. they'll be in the  `while($row=$db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {` function, so when I use session and echo the values are always the first value of the array?

Answer (score 2):

sessions to the rescue

```
$key = $_SESSION['key'] ?? ( $_SESSION['key'] = array_rand($a) );
echo $key;
```

remember that this only works if you have a session, so if you don't, you'll also need to run `session_start();` first.

Comment: **Remember:** Null coalesce operator (??) is introduced in version 7 of PHP. If you're already using php 7 then i highly recommend to use the latest syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Another possiblity would be to rewrite your code using `rand()`, and then seed it beforehand with `srand()`